# POSTMAN error: Unresolved Variable: "This variable is not defined in the active collection, environment or globals."

Tags: postman

trying to test changes I made to an API I'm working on and I get this error for the host... I was told previously to update my postman app which I did and I am still receiving the same error...  any ideas??

[image]

Comment: You have unsaved changes on the environment tab, is this a new variable that you have just added?

Answer (score 3):

You need to select one of the environments as the working environment.
This is done through the Environments tab (left side) and then select the desired enviornment and select it as active.

[image: Activate it by pressing the button on the left side]

Comment: And if you haven't hit the 'save' button on the environment, do that as well.

Comment: it was well hidden didn't find it at the first try :D